# How to consume a webApi from asp.net Web API to store result in json file

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

How to consume RestApi using c# and to store the content of responses in json file? i.e When I run the program, it should call API and automatically it should store the json content in json file.
How can it be possible using Asp.Net?

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTTP POST

```
using System.Net.Https; // Add this library

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var values = "DataToSend";

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://sit.com/sample.aspx", content);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //JSON
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call any rest api using httpclient(Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client)

Following method returns a json string async which you can save later

```
static async Taskstring> GetContentAsync(string path)
{
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(address);
}
```

to get json content synchronously

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = client.GetAsync("http://example.com").Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {    

        string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Console.WriteLine(responseString);//you can save the responseString here
    }
}
```

or use open source library like  RestSharp

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");        
// execute the request
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

More examples can be found https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client  or using  [restsharp](http://restsharp.org/)